# Exception EReadError in module rtl170.bpl - RichEdit1.Zoom: Property Zoom does not exists

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I used my DelphiXE3 instance normally just a couple of days ago.
Now it complains when running:
[image]
[image]

Ignoring the error message the Delphi IDE works as usual: it regulary loads and compiles (and builds) my projects. I compiled and run a test project with a TRichEdit component too without any error messages.
But if I click on "Ok" button on the latter message Delphi is closed.

I found the rtl170.bpl in

```
...\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\bin
```

and

```
...\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\Redist\win32
```

folders. Both datetime are 23 jan 2013 00:55. They seems not modified (I suspected a malware action).
I remember a Wiindows 10 update occurred a few days ago.
I've not asked Ebarcadero support now. 
Anybody else with similar issue?

Comment: Naturally you want to blame a Windows 10 update, but the reality is that almost certainly this is down to something you did. Cut the project down to a minimal repro and post it. Until then, there's probably no question here.

Comment: TRichEdit.Zoom only exists in recent versions of Windows (after theme support was added). My suspicion is that you've turned off Windows theme  support (Project->Options->Application, Enable Runtime Themes) and it's causing the manifest to not be added that loads the proper common controls library.

Comment: No project to deal with at all (demo or configuration): the issue is Delphi XE3 IDE shows error messages when started (empty, no project loaded). I've Delphi 10 Seattle and Delphi 2007 installed on the same machine. In the past a Windows 10 updates caused "borland.delphi.targets" disappeared (question on SO).

Comment: What's more likely is that you have installed a package that is registering an incompatible TRichEdit.

Comment: Thanks to previous comments I focused on some package including code for most recent RTL, and updating IW packages solved the issue. I'll post a report to IW support.

Answer (score 0):

The package IW 14.1.7 seems to be the issue origin.
Installing Intraweb 14.1.8 fix the problem.